# r - using the output of of Lasso regression to index original dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to use the output of the significant predictor variables that I obtained from running a lasso regression to narrow down the number of variables I place in my logistic regression function, but am having trouble properly indexing the original dataset to create a subset of my data.

I was able to pull out the non-zero variables from my lasso model using:

```
lasso.coef = colnames(stocks.transform)[which(coef(lasso.mod,s=bestlam)!=0)]
lasso.coef
```

This yielded a vector of all the non-zero attributes. I want to use this vector to index my original data set stock.transform:

```
lasso.out = stocks.transform[lasso.coef]
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(stocks.transform, lasso.coef) : 
 undefined columns selected
```

I am unsure how to define the column any further.

Comment: `stocks.transform[lasso.coef,]`. You're not providing a vector of columns to select. If you want all the columns, then the provided code should work.

Comment: @Abdou I tried that but it just gives me a vector of <NA> for my data values

Comment: Without a sight of the actual output, I cannot help any further. Create a dummy dataset, generate the model and try indexing. Edit your post with that.